# Why won't my CSS load in AWS Lambda?

Tags: php, css, amazon-web-services, lambda, slim

I uploaded my Slim project to AWS Lambda following this tutorial: https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/

Since Laravel and Slim are quite similar, I was able to run my project.

However, my stylesheets and JS won't load with the page.
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY1zV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This is because I did not define a route. So, it doesn't return anything. Fixed it by uploading my CSS to S3 instead.